# Sharepoint 2010 - bind listview error message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, list-view, application-pages, databind

I have an application page which retieve data from a stored procedure, my page give me the desired result but I discovrer in log table that this page have an error

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PWC.SharePoint.Common.Layouts.PWC.RejectedReassessments.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
```

when I debug I found this error in the line :

> this.ReassessmentSelectorDataPager.DataBind();

this is the part of the code, I can't have further details

```
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        this.EnsureChildControls();

        try
        {

            this.ApprovedReassessmentsListView.DataBind();
            BindReassessmentSelectorToControl();
            this.ReassessmentSelectorDataPager.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingUtilities.LogToDatabase(PWC_LOG_TYPE.ERROR, ex.Message, ex.ToString(), this.currentWeb.Url, this.currentWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName);
        }
    }
```

Help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand, When you debug you get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at the `data pager` control `this.ReassessmentSelectorDataPager.DataBind();`

This issue occurs if you tried at your code to set data pager `ReassessmentSelectorDataPager` programmatically to `null` like this `DataPager ReassessmentSelectorDataPager = null;` so make sure that it's not set to null at any line in your code.

Also , no need to bind data pager control like this `this.ReassessmentSelectorDataPager.DataBind();` it's related to a specific `list view` that should be defined at `PagedControlID` property at `asp:DataPager` tag, so you need to set the data source of this listview then bind it like this

```
 ListView1.DataSource = fucctionthat will retrive data to list view();
 ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, actually I added in listview pagepropertieschanging and this code '    protected void ReassessmentSelectorListView_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
        {            try
            {               this.ReassessmentSelectorDataPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);     }       catch (Exception ex)
            {    LoggingUtilities.LogToDatabase(LOG_TYPE.ERROR, ex.Message, ex.ToString(), this.currentWeb.Url, this.currentWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName);   } }'